# Not able to import a module in python

Tags: python, django

I was making a django application .When i tried to import the `models.py` module in `forms.py` by the following command `from . import models` it raises the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\practise_project\practise_app\forms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import models
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

The directory structure is shown in the image.[image]

Comment: Just use `import models`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative imports in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: to test the package you need to run a script outside of the package and `import practise_app.forms` for example. Or if forms.py should be runnable as main you can add a check: `if __name__ == "__main__":import models ; else:from . import models`